# Array of objects prints blank string

Tags: c++, arrays, string

(The issue has been solved and the solution has been added as comment line to main.cpp)

The problem I'm having is described in the main.cpp file. I already checked another questions about this and none of them really helped.

I'm trying to create a console application with C++ where you can add BOOKS to the LIBRARY. In the library class, there is a **displayInfo**() function which displays the info of a particular book. It can display integer or double valued informations without having a problem however it is having a trouble when I try to display string typed informations. It just prints blank. Let me give you a little sample of my code.

***Here is Book.h***

```
#ifndef BOOK_H
#define BOOK_H
#include <string>

class Book
{
    friend class Library;
public:
    void setName();
    std::string getName();
private:
    std::string nameOfBook;
};

#endif
```

***Book.cpp***

```
#include "Book.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void Book::setName()
{
    string nameOfBook;
    cout << "Please enter the name of the book: ";
    cin >> nameOfBook;
    this->nameOfBook = nameOfBook;
}

string Book::getName()
{
    return nameOfBook;
}
```

***Library.h***

```
#ifndef LIBRARY_H
#define LIBRARY_H

#include "Book.h"
#include <array>

class Library
{
private:
    std::array <Book , 10> bookArray; // I have to use this

public:
    void addBook();
    void displayInfo();
};

#endif
```

***Library.cpp***

```
#include "Library.h"
#include "Book.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

void Library::addBook()
{
    bookArray[0].setName();
}

void Library::displayInfo() 
{
    cout << "The book: " << bookArray[0].getName() << endl;
}
```

***And main.cpp***

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Book.h"
#include "Library.h"
#include <string>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // The problem is solved
    // Create the objects out of the loop
    // Library obj1 <---- this solved it
    while (true)
    {

        int number; // Ask user what to do
        cout << "Press 1 to add a book\n"
             << "Press 2 to display info\n"
             << "Press 0 to quit\n";
        cin >> number;
        if (number == 1) // Add a book
        {
            Library obj1; // <------ THIS IS WRONG
            obj1.addBook(); // Consider we named the book as 'Fly'
        }
        else if (number == 2)   
        {
            Library obj1; // <------ THIS IS WRONG
            obj1.displayInfo(); // ******* The output I'm expecting is The Book: Fly
                                // But instead, it only gives me The Book:
            // I have 4 more strings like this in the main project and all of them have the same problem
        }
        else if (number == 0) // Everything else
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Wrong input\n";
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
I coded this with VS Code and compiled it with MinGW (8.2.0) if it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one problem in your code is that you have many instances of a library class so **addBook** is landing in one object and **displayInfo** in a new one (empty one)

you have to:

```
int main()
{
    Library obj1; // declare the lib in scope for all the cases
    while (true)
    {
        int number; // Ask user what to do
        cout << "Press 1 to add a book\n"
             << "Press 2 to display info\n"
             << "Press 0 to quit\n";
        cin >> number;
        if (number == 1) // Add a book
        {

            obj1.addBook(); // Consider we named the book as 'Fly'
        }
        else if (number == 2)   
        {
            //Library obj1;
            obj1.displayInfo(); // ******* The output I'm expecting is The Book: Fly
                                // But instead, it only gives me The Book:
            // I have 4 more strings like this in the main project and all of them have the same problem
        }
        else if (number == 0) // Everything else
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Wrong input\n";
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u are creating the object again in every iteration of the loop. therefore overwriting the old object that has been given a name.

Comment: please add the code that solve the problem in the question